# how to write this sql statement?

Tags: sql

```
id  login_name login_time
1    aa        2002-09-19
2    bb        2002-12-19
3    bb        2002-12-30
```

How do I write one SQL statement to find out the latest login_time for the user who has the maximum number of logins. For example, in this sample data, user "bb" has logged in twice and his latest login_time is '2002-12-30'.

Comment: What do you mean by 'maximum login times'?

Comment: What SQL variant? Answers will differ for mysql, t-sql, etc

Comment: Maximum number of logins perhaps?

Comment: the user 'bb' logged in two times.

Comment: By 'maximum login times' do you mean *most recent* or *earliest*? Or is there some kind of record of time spent logged-in?

Comment: the expected output is '2002-12-30'

Comment: How do you want to deal with ties, say if user "aa" had another record for instance...

Comment: it's just a general sql question, should not depends on specific database servers.

Comment: Homework, if not dependant on specific database?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT

id,
MAX(`login_time`) AS `login_time`

FROM table_name

GROUP BY login_name
```

Is this what you want ?? can you explain a bit more if not ..

Answer (score 2):

Here's the easy way:

```
SELECT
    t.login_name
    ,COUNT(t.id) AS login_counts
    ,MAX(t.login_time) AS latest_login_time
FROM this_table AS t
GROUP BY t.login_name
ORDER BY login_counts DESC, login_name
;
```

The top line gives you the `login_name` with the most logins.

And here's the hard way:

```
SELECT
   t.login_name
   ,MAX(t.login_time) AS latest_login_time
FROM this_table AS t
INNER JOIN (
   -- Determine who has the most logins
   SELECT TOP 1 x.login_name, COUNT(x.id) AS login_count
   FROM this_table AS x
   GROUP BY x.login_name
   ORDER BY login_count DESC  -- to get the highest counts first
) AS m
   ON t.login_name = m.login_name
GROUP BY t.login_name
;
```

That gets you one name and date, and that's it, though it doesn't take into account the possibility that there could be more than 1 name with the maximum number of logins. I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT login_name, COUNT(*) as num_logins, max(login_time) as last_login_time
FROM table_name ORDER BY num_logins DESC
```

Then, depends on sql server you are using, you can add `limit 1` (in case of mysql), or `top 1` for MS SQL Server, or something else for a different server to get the first record only.

Comment: Perhaps you should expand on what is wrong about it so that the poster and others might have a better idea of what you're looking to get.

Comment: @alex07 - I think that you want a `GROUP BY login_name` in there.

Answer (score 0):

The following works on an Oracle database:

```
SELECT MAX(LOGIN_TIME)
  FROM LOGIN_TABLE
  WHERE LOGIN_NAME = (SELECT LOGIN_NAME
                        FROM (SELECT LOGIN_NAME, COUNT(*) AS LOGIN_COUNT
                                FROM LOGIN_TABLE
                                GROUP BY LOGIN_NAME
                                ORDER BY LOGIN_COUNT DESC)
                        WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * 
from [login table] 
where login_name [has max] on login_time [is soonest]
```